# Can PayloadValidatingInterceptor be used to validate for required fields

Tags: spring-ws

We are using the PayloadValidatingInterceptor default implementation but found that it does not validate the required fields. Is there a way to validate that the required fields are also  present using PayloadValidatingInterceptor.

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it should work with the the configured XSD files. Perhaps you didn't correctly define a field to be mandatory in your XSD?

Perhaps you've incorrectly configured the interceptor. I've configured one like this:

```
@Bean
public PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor() {
    PayloadValidatingInterceptor interceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setSchema(messagesXsdResource);
    interceptor.setAddValidationErrorDetail(true);

    return interceptor;
}
```

And of course it should be added as an interceptor to the `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping`

```
@Bean
public PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping endpointMapping() {
    PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping mapping = new PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping();
    mapping.setInterceptors(new EndpointInterceptor[]{
        otherInterceptor(),
        validatingInterceptor()
    });

    return mapping;
}
```

But I'm just guessing, you should provide more context for a good answer.

Comment: I used the PayloadValidatingInterceptorWithSourceFix class to do the trick and now it works as expected. This gave me more control over validation. Thanks for the reply @evandongen